# Throwing OutOfMemoryError using Jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, android, jackson, realm, objectmapper

I'm trying to get a JSON format string from ObjectMapper inside a AsyncTask thread and I keep getting OutOfMemoryError
And in the manifest file already have add the line

Manifest file:

```
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

AsyncTask method executed in doInBackground:

```
    String url = "/plano/fiscalizacao/fiscalizar";

    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();


    Fiscalizacao fiscalizacao = RealmOperations.getFiscalizacaoById(realm, idFiscalizacao);

    if (fiscalizacao == null)
        return;

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapperProvider().createDefaultObjectMapper();

    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(fiscalizacao);

    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json, "UTF-8");
    //HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    HttpResponse response = WebServiceSupport.post(context, url, entity);

    if (WebServiceSupport.validaStatus(response)) {
        String str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
    }
```

Fiscalizacao class:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Nullable
private Date dataFiscalizacao;
@Nullable
private PlanoFiscalizacaoProcesso plano;
@Nullable
private String relatorio;
@Nullable
private Reparticao reparticao;
@PrimaryKey
private Long selfId;
@Nullable
private SyncStatus status_sync;
private TipoGrauAproveitamento tipoGrauAproveitamento;
private TipoMedida tipoMedida;
@Nullable
private Date versionDate;
```

Stacktrace to the problem im having:

```
08-22 14:04:12.623 22737-32404/exi.co.mz.sigit.fiscalizacao E/UncaughtException:
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 524300 byte allocation with 277842 free bytes and 271KB until OOM
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer._charArray(TextBuffer.java:716)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer.expand(TextBuffer.java:675)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer.append(TextBuffer.java:471)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.SegmentedStringWriter.write(SegmentedStringWriter.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator.writeRaw(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:476)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultPrettyPrinter$Lf2SpacesIndenter.writeIndentation(DefaultPrettyPrinter.java:382)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultPrettyPrinter.writeEndObject(DefaultPrettyPrinter.java:247)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator.writeEndObject(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:179)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator.close(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:882)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:2727)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2210)
    at exi.co.mz.fiscalizacao.rest.ParcelaClient.setFiscalizacao(ParcelaClient.java:184)
    at exi.co.mz.fiscalizacao.rest.ParcelaClient.doInBackground(ParcelaClient.java:239)
    at exi.co.mz.fiscalizacao.rest.ParcelaClient.doInBackground(ParcelaClient.java:33)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Continuing stacktrace:

```
08-22 14:04:12.923 22737-32404/exi.co.mz.sigit.fiscalizacao E/AndroidRuntime:
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
Process: exi.co.mz.sigit.fiscalizacao, PID: 22737
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Trying to be on standards of to much code:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 524300 byte allocation with 277842 free bytes and 271KB until OOM
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer._charArray(TextBuffer.java:716)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer.expand(TextBuffer.java:675)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer.append(TextBuffer.java:471)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.SegmentedStringWriter.write(SegmentedStringWriter.java:67)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator.writeRaw(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:476)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultPrettyPrinter$Lf2SpacesIndenter.writeIndentation(DefaultPrettyPrinter.java:382)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultPrettyPrinter.writeEndObject(DefaultPrettyPrinter.java:247)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator.writeEndObject(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:179)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator.close(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:882)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:2727)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2210)
at exi.co.mz.fiscalizacao.rest.ParcelaClient.setFiscalizacao(ParcelaClient.java:184)
at exi.co.mz.fiscalizacao.rest.ParcelaClient.doInBackground(ParcelaClient.java:239)
at exi.co.mz.fiscalizacao.rest.ParcelaClient.doInBackground(ParcelaClient.java:33)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 524300 byte allocation with 277842 free bytes and 271KB until OOM
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer._charArray(TextBuffer.java:716)
                                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer.expand(TextBuffer.java:675)

Comment: Please edit your question and include the stacktrace. That'll help in diagnosing your problem.

Comment: its as been edited my friend

Comment: Your problem appears to be that you are reading to much information back in the line "mapper.writeValueAsString(fiscalizacao)". I'd recommend trying to receive the data in much smaller chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution

When working with Realm, is necessary to extract the Object from realm data base using .copyFromRealm()

```
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    Fiscalizacao fiscalizacao = realm.copyFromRealm(RealmOperations.getFiscalizacaoById(realm, idFiscalizacao));
```

Comment: Before JSON serialization, it can be a good idea to make object detached, but not necessarily in every scenario